Why do the enemy sprites disappear from the screen when they reach the edge of the screen?
I am currently trying to write a version of space invaders using p5.play (it's the language that my particular college uses) but whenever the sprites reach the right edge of the screen they all disappear and I can't figure out why. I'm relatively new to the environment and modified the code to work with classes but now I'm stuck.
I've included the code in the hope that someone will be able to help.
let stars;
let star;
let numStars;

let players;
let player; 
let playerWidth;
let playerHeight;

let alienImg;
let enemies;
let enemy;

let left;
let right;

let rows;
let cols;

function preload() {
  alienImg = loadImage('images/alien11s.png');
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  stars = new Group();
  players = new Group();
  enemies = new Group();

  numStars = random(100, 250);
  for(let x = 0; x < numStars; x++) {
    star = new Star();
    stars.add(star.sprite);
  }

  playerWidth = 50;
  playerHeight = 20;
  player = new Player();
  players.add(player.sprite);

  rows = 5;
  cols = 10;

  for(let x = 1; x < cols + 1; x++) {
    for(let y = 1; y < rows + 1; y++) {
      enemy = new Enemy(x, y);
      enemies.add(enemy.sprite);
    }
  }
  
}

function draw() {
  background('black');
  left = false;
  right = false;

  for(let i = 0; i < enemies.length; i++) {
    if(enemies[i].position.x == 0){
      right = true;
    } else if(enemies[i].position.x == windowWidth) {
      left = true;
    }
  }

  if(right) {
    for(let i = 0; i < enemies.length; i++) {
      enemies[i].position.y += enemies.h;
      enemies[i].vel.x *= -1;
    }
  }else if(left) {
    for(let i = 0; i < enemies.length; i++) {
      enemies[i].position.y += enemies.h;
      enemies[i].vel.x *= -1;
    }
  }

  stars.draw();
  player.playerMove();
  players.draw();
  for(let i = 0; i < enemies.length; i++) {
    enemies[i].move();
  }
  enemies.draw();
}


class Star {
  constructor() {
    this.posX = random(5, windowWidth - 5);
    this.posY = random(5, windowHeight - 5);
    this.sprite = createSprite(this.posX, this.posY);
    this.sprite.diameter = 2;
    this.sprite.collider = 'n';
    this.sprite.shapeColor = color('yellow');
  }
}

class Player {
  constructor() {
    this.sprite = createSprite(windowWidth / 2, windowHeight - playerHeight, playerWidth, playerHeight)
  }

  playerMove() {
    if(kb.pressing('left')) {
      this.sprite.move(5, 'left', 5);
    }else if(kb.pressing('right')) {
      this.sprite.move(5, 'right', 5);
    }
  }
}

class Enemy {
  constructor(posX, posY) {
    this.w = 40;
    this.h = 40;
    this.speed = 5;
    this.sprite = createSprite(posX * this.w * 2, posY * this.h * 2, this.w, this.h);
    this.sprite.vel.x = 3;
    this.sprite.image = alienImg;
    this.sprite.scale = 0.5;
    this.sprite.collider = 'n';
  }

  move() {

    this.sprite.pos.x += this.sprite.vel.x;
  }
}


I've modified the code from an online tutorial which doesn't use classes. What should happen is that the sprites reach the edge of the screen, move down, and then change direction.
